# Cars following two different application layers

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am building an attack scenario where a vehicle, *attacker*, follows another vehicle, *normal*. The *attacker* starts sending BSMs with faulty position data to make *normal* stop on the road that it is traveling.

I have implemented `AttackerCarApplLayer` for *attacker* to use functions defined for it specifically and `NormalCarApplLayer` for *normal*.

I have defined the TraCIScenarioManager settings in omnetpp.ini as follows:

```
##########################################################
#            TraCIScenarioManager parameters             #
##########################################################
*.manager.updateInterval = 0.1s
*.manager.host = "localhost"
*.manager.port = 9999
*.manager.moduleType = "org.car2x.veins.nodes.AttackerCar"
*.manager.moduleName = "attacker"
*.manager.moduleType = "org.car2x.veins.nodes.Car"
*.manager.moduleName = "car"
*.manager.moduleDisplayString = ""
*.manager.autoShutdown = true
*.manager.margin = 25
#launch config. tells Veins which SUMO configuration to run
*.manager.configFile = "newyork.sumo.cfg"
#launch command. change sumo-gui with sumo depending on what you want to launch
*.manager.commandLine = "sumo-gui --remote-port $port --seed $seed --configuration-file $configFile"
```

And `NormalCarWaveApplLayer` settings as:

```
##########################################################
#                    WaveAppLayer                        #
##########################################################
*.car[*].applType = "NormalCarApplLayer"
*.car[*].appl.debug = false
*.car[*].appl.headerLength = 256 bit
*.car[*].appl.sendBeacons = true
*.car[*].appl.dataOnSch = false
*.car[*].appl.beaconInterval = 1s
*.car[*].appl.beaconPriority = 3
*.car[*].appl.dataPriority = 2
*.car[*].appl.maxOffset = 0.005s
*.car[*].appl.avoidBeaconSynchronization = true
```

And `AttackerCarWaveApplLayer` settings as:

```
##########################################################
#                   Attacker WaveAppLayer                #
##########################################################
*.attacker[*].applType = "AttackerCarApplLayer"
*.attacker[*].appl.debug = false
*.attacker[*].appl.headerLength = 256 bit
*.attacker[*].appl.sendBeacons = true
*.attacker[*].appl.dataOnSch = false
*.attacker[*].appl.beaconInterval = 1s
*.attacker[*].appl.beaconPriority = 3
*.attacker[*].appl.dataPriority = 2
*.attacker[*].appl.maxOffset = 0.005s
*.attacker[*].appl.avoidBeaconSynchronization = true
```

When the simulation launches, only `AttackerCarApplLayer` is instantiated for both *normal* and *attacker*. Is this the correct way to achieve my goal? If not, please suggest what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently specifying `moduleType` and `moduleName` twice in your simulation's `.ini` file. The default behavior of OMNeT++ to use the first value it finds for a parameter. This is unlikely to be what you want. If you can use different SUMO vehicle types for your attackers and normal cars, here is how you can solve your problem instead:

Veins 4.5 allows you to use different values for `moduleType`, `moduleName`, and `moduleDisplayString` depending on the SUMO vehicle type. Simply set one SUMO vehicle type for your attackers, for example `ATTACK`, then refer to the syntax of https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L63 to set per-type configurations in your `.ini` file. For example, `*.manager.moduleName = "ATTACK=attacker *=car"`

Comment: Thanks @christoph-sommer. I will try this. However, for now, I have created two classes `Car` and `AttackerCar`. I have created a `TrafficManager` class that generates all the vehicles through Veins. The `TrafficManager` keeps a vector of these vehicles as a map while creating them. I use `dynamic_cast<AttackerCar*>(car)` to make the application layer behave differently for when it is instantiated for an _attacker_. Then I call the functions defined in the `AttackerCar` class to initiate the attack.